# Dynamic Table Continuous <td> Count

Tags: php

I am stuck in a weird problem, I want to show the continuous number till the last in the row and cols,
instead of that its showing form 1-50 and then again the row starts with 1 up-to 50.

```
<?php
  $rows = 10;
  $cols = 50;
  $x=1 ;
  echo "<table border='1'>"; 
  for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

     echo "<tr>";

    for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
           echo "<td>$td</td>";
    }
       echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are starting the `td` count from 1 for every row in your for loop. That's why you get the counts from 1-50 for every row 10 times. The starting value of `$td` should itself be a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rows = 10;
$cols = 50;
$x=1 ;
echo "<table border='1'>"; 
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

  $style = "green";
  if ($tr % 2 == 0) {
    $style = "#ccc";
  }
  echo "<tr style='background-color:".$style."'>";

  for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
  {

       echo "<td>$x</td>";
       $x++;

  }
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yeah that works ! And how to color one row and one is not colored ?

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting $td which resets at every new tablerow. 
Instead, you would like to output an incrementing $x, if I'm not mistaken.

```
 <?php
 $rows = 10;
 $cols = 50;
 $x=1 ;
 echo "<table border='1'>"; 

 for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){  
   echo "<tr>";

     for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
         echo "<td>" . $x . "</td>";
         $x++;
      }

   echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

In response to your comment on another answer: if you would want alternating row colors, you could use $tr and check wether it is even or uneven:

```
if($tr % 2 == 0)
{
 // use color1
}
else
{
 // use color2
}
```